# Is there any reason if HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR changes sometimes?

Tags: php, hosting

My site is watching the IP of visitors, using `$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']` variable. Although, very rare occasions, it returns with different IP than the actual one (not to totally different, same inside my country). What could it be? I dont know anything about my hosting infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']` have you tried using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to grab the visitors/users IP

EDIT: 
Try the above or for an easier and tested output use this

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
echo $ip;
```

Comment: it returns an internal address :( 10.10.1.254

Comment: yes, that means you logged in or visited your site using localhost. try connecting to the site using the domain name and you will see it produce the IP of the user.

Comment: I have just tested this on my local site and production and this seems to grab my real ip `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);`